# How to vectorize this for-loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector, vectorization

This is perhaps a simple question. I have a vector and a matrix and want to make a new matrix based on some manipulation. I constructed the new matrix using for loop and I would like to know how can I write it with Vector operator that are likely faster.

```
d=[n x 1];
t= [n x n];
```

I want the new Delta matrix which is [n x n] as follows:

```
for i=1:39
    for j=1:39
  Delta(i,j)=d(i)-d(j)-t(i,j);
    end
end
```

The result

```
[d (1) - d (1) - t( 1 ,1),d (1) - d (2) - t( 1 ,2), ...   d(1) - d (39) -  t( 1 ,39)
 d (2) - d (1) - t( 2 ,1),d (2) - d (2) - t( 2 ,2), .... ,d (2) - d (39) - t( 2 ,39)  
.                                                                     
.
.
d (38) - d (1) - t( 38 ,1),d (38) - d (2) - t( 38 ,2), ... , d(38) -d (39)-t(38,39)  
d (39) - d (1) - t( 39 ,1),d (39) - d (2) - t( 39 ,2), ...,  d(39)- d (39)- t(39 ,39)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the efficient [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
Delta = bsxfun(@minus,d,d.') - t
```

Comment: Hey Thank you so much @divakar I don't know what it is. But I tested and it works great :))